# useEffect array dependency is called in every render when array is not changed

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    { name: "a" },
    { name: "b" },
    { name: "c" }
  ]);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const addName = () => setColumns([...columns, { name: "r" }]);
  const toggleOpen = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
    <>
      <List columns={columns} />
      <button onClick={toggleOpen}>Toggle</button>
      <button onClick={addName}>Add</button>
      <p>{isOpen.toString()}</p>
    </>
  );
}

const List = ({ columns }) => {
  const names = columns.map(col => col.name);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Names is changed to: ", names);
  }, [names]);

  return <p>{names.join(" ")}</p>;
};
```

`Names is changed to:` is called, when `isOpen` state is changed in `App` component. 
I want the `console.log` to be executed only when names array is changed.
I think in `List` component, it is creating a new array whenever render, so that the previous array and the new array are not equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You [should memoize the component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) so it will render **only on props change** (or if comparison function passed as 2nd argument).

Currently, `List` rendered due to its parent `App` render.

```
const List = ({ columns }) => {
  const names = columns.map((col) => col.name);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Names is changed to: ", names);
  }, [names]);

  return <p>{names.join(" ")}</p>;
};

const MemoList = React.memo(List);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <MemoList columns={columns} />
    </>
  );
}
```

See working example:

[image: Edit polished-pine-j17om]

---

For class component, use [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) or implement `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks, how about for class components?

Comment: `React.PureComponent` & `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: `React.memo` will not help if `List` will utilize other props and/or state

Answer (score 3):

```
const names = columns.map(col => col.name);
```

Creates a new array every time and `useEffect` thinks that dependencies have changed.

To avoid that either pass `names` directly to `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Names is changed to: ", names);
  }, names);
```

Or `useMemo` to get the same array object:

```
const names = useMemo(() => columns.map(
   col => col.name
), [columns]);
```

Comment: thanks, what is the difference between passing a dependency in an array or directly passing the dependency?

Comment: `names` is an array, so you pass it's content as dependency. If you pass `[names]` only the reference to the array is checked.